# How long does it take coffee beans to degas?

Tags: beans, roasting, storage

A google search brings up a great article by Hannah from Fellow Products called "Understanding Degassing: Is Fresh Best?," in which she claims:

> Degassing varies depending on the type of coffee and roast. It therefore can take anywhere from 2 to 12 days until the coffee is ready to brew. Some rules of thumb:
>
> The first 24 hours is when a bulk (approximately 40%) of CO2 leaves the bean.
>
> Darker roasts usually degas faster than lighter roasts
>
> Longer roasts usually degas faster than faster roasts.

Is anyone aware of any other research on this topic?  Can anyone corroborate, or does anyone disagree?

Comment: I regularly roast a natural processed Ethiopian Yirgacheffe and find it takes more like a week before is has sufficiently degassed to be able to brew without foaming excessively.  And I put it under a slight vacuum right after roasting to try and speed it up a bit.

Comment: How do you put it under a vacuum?  And how do you store it after that?  Any thoughts on valves?  Thank you!

Comment: I use a Vacu-Vin wine vacuum pump.  I just take an empty (clean) wine bottle and fill it with freshly roasted beans, then pump out as much air as I can with the Vacu-Vin.  I repeat for a day or two and it's really surprising how much gas accumulates in the bottle for the first couple of days.  After day 3 or 4 it's obvious that no more C02 is coming off the beans so I just use that as my storage system too.

Comment: I don't know how to link to a previous question but look up question #2881 and I posted a picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Degassing is discussed a few times. The most cited answer in [Coffee SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) is probably [this question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/6/why-is-it-not-recommended-to-drink-coffee-immediately-after-its-roasted).

In short:

- Degassing takes up to 2 to 4 days to achieve drinkable coffee. If you really want to shorten this, grind earlier. But you should try yourself for best timing.
- The best flavor is around 1 to 2 weeks. Again, you should follow your taste buds based on the beans and the roast degree.

Answer (score 1):

Another major component when talking about degassing is whether or not the coffee is ground or not...

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0963996914000337#st0015

Comment: Bob, I was under the impression that it's best to grind the coffee only just before brewing.  Is there another camp of thought on this?

Comment: Generally it is best to grind right before brewing. However that is not practical all the time. Once ground coffee is considered stale within a half an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Degassing - what a lovely topic.

May i offer an experience is that, regardless of roast:
of course one can grind anytime,

- central american coffees seem generally to take about a week to be truly flavourful after roasing - whether this is all down to degassing per se or just being in the air for that time as well, dunno - just experience.
- african coffees can be ready in 36 - 48 hours -

as for STALE-ness half hour after grinding?

well - have you tried it?

I've been surprised and delighted when having to travel with ground coffee - that it can be absolutely fantastic.

there's an aeropress method that was a world champion win in 2016 perhaps? that deliberately used "ground the night before" beans.

personally i love the privilege of grinding right before brewing, but i am surprised at how good/different ground coffee can be over the course of a week's road trip travelling with a plastic V60 01, some filters and a heating coil when not likely to have a kettle close by (sadly common in US hotels).

-m.c.

Comment: this is very interesting. thanks.  Where did you get this info that degassing varies based on origin?
What about Indonesian/Moka Java, et.al.  ??